# TFS 2013 : Create when an item is commented

Tags: tfs, tfs-alerts

Can I create an alert when a comment is added on a work item ?
I've found nothing convenient so far and I don't know if it's only possible.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create an alert to fire when a Work Item is updated.

Go to "Web Access | Cog | Alerts" and configure a "work item changed" alert.

You may be able to add a "history" filter but tge first option will work.

Comment: I tried but we got an alert every time the  work item was changed, I failed to filter on the "comment" action.
Eventually, we found a workaround by using both the "notify when affected" and affecting the item to the person whose answer is waited.
Thx anyway for your response !